# .zip Files BruteForcer with Python 3.8

Tags: python, scripting, zip

I recently coded myself a BruteForcer for .zip files using only Python with Zipfile lib. Here is the code:

```
import zipfile

charlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
complete = []

for current in range(4):
    a = [i for i in charlist]
    for x in range(current):
        a = [y + i for i in charlist for y in a]
    complete = complete + a

z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')

tries = 0

for password in complete:
    try:
        tries += 1
        z.setpassword(password.encode('ascii'))
        z.extract('test.txt')
        print(f'Password was found after {tries} tries! It was {password}!')
        break
    except:
        pass
```

I also made a .zip file called test.zip which has 4 character encryption with only lowwercase letters.
The error is that whenever I run it, no matter where (I use PyCharm IDE and Kali, but I tried using VS Code) it returns this popup 'Process finished with exit code 0', which means that PC procceded it but didn't returned anything. Also print() is not a problem, because it was supposed to make a .txt file where there will be the password of the .zip file, but it didn't do it. I appreciate any type of help.

Comment: Your code worked just fine when I run it from a shell.   It correctly found the password.

Comment: Then how it doesn't work for me Frank?

Comment: Just wondering if it's something unexpected.  Are you sure the name of the file inside the zip file is "test.txt", and not spelled differently or inside a directory? 

Your code could be made a little bit safer by only catching RuntimeError (error on bad password) rather than all possible errors.

Comment: Yes, it is, and how should I launch it, with PyCharm or what? How did You launched it? It only returns the same error as it did previously.

Comment: Frank, it just took a little bit longer to return nothing than previous times.